what variation of traveling salesperson acts like an amusement park, where there is time to walk between rides, but variable wait times through day
I want to build a way to figure out paths around an amusement park. Let's say I have an estimate on how long it will take to stand in line at each attraction at different times, and I know how long to walk between them and the duration of the ride. Also there is constraints that I must eat at a certain time. Is this a variation of the traveling salesperson? I don't know how to account for adjustments in the cost to visit attractions at different times of the day, or how to get the nodes in place for meal times (or showtimes)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Here are a few references:

Cardiff, M., Hughes, G., & Bosch, R. (2000). Maximizing Fun at a Theme Park. UMAP Journal, 483.
Bouzarth, E. L., Forrester, R. J., Hutson, K. R., Isaac, R., Midkiff, J., Rivers, D., & Testa, L. J. (2018). A comparison of algorithms for finding an efficient theme park tour. Journal of Applied Mathematics, 2018(1), 2453185.
Glowski, A. (2023). Optimizing Fun: A TSP-Based Approach to Route Optimization at Disneyland.

